# PyQt5 type conversion from QML

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I'm trying to fill a QML list model from python and on a button press, I'd like to get the item I set previously.

I ran into type conversion problems, where I get QObject instead of a python dictionary.

Create a class which gets pushed to the QML root context. The pySignal is invoked by QML javascript code

```py
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlComponent, QJSValue
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlEngine, QQmlComponent


class PythonContext(QObject):

    pySignal = pyqtSignal(QJSValue)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.pySignal.connect(self.onPySignal)

    @pyqtSlot(QJSValue)
    def onPySignal(self, param):
        obj = param.toVariant()
        print('onPySignal', obj)
        print(dir(obj))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlEngine()

    pyContext = PythonContext()

    ctxt = engine.rootContext()
    ctxt.setContextProperty('py', pyContext)

    component = QQmlComponent(engine)
    component.loadUrl(QUrl('qml_signals.qml'))

    obj = component.create()

    obj.addListItem({'pk': 1, 'name': 'One'})
    obj.addListItem({'pk': 2, 'name': 'Two'})
    obj.addListItem({'pk': 3, 'name': 'Three'})

    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The QML file itself only contains an application window with a ComboBox and a button. A button press invokes the pySignal emission and should send the item currently selected by the ComboBox to the Python context.

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

ApplicationWindow {

    title: "PyQT5 QML Signals dictionary"

    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    function addListItem(param) {
        lm.append(param)
        if(lmSelector.count == 1) {
            lmSelector.currentIndex = 0
        }
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ComboBox {
            id: lmSelector
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter

            textRole: "name"

            model: ListModel {
                id: lm
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "button"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
            onClicked: {
                var selectedObject = lm.get(lmSelector.currentIndex)

                console.log("button clicked" + selectedObject.name)

                /* this does not work */
                py.pySignal(selectedObject)

                /* but this does and gives the desired output */
                py.pySignal({ name: selectedObject.name, pk: selectedObject.pk})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```py
onPySignal <PyQt5.QtCore.QObject object at 0x03CA4710>
```

What I would expect is:

```py
onPySignal {'name': 'One', 'pk': 1.0}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited the code. Sorry about that, I hacked this in just before leaving...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you pass a dictionary such as data to the ListModel, it stores it in QObjects so you can implement the binding required. Therefore, the [`get()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method) method of ListModel returns a object(QObject):

> object get(int index)

f you want to recover the dictionary then you must convert that object to JSON, and from JSON to dictionary:

```
// ...
/* this work */
py.pySignal(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedObject)))
// ...
```

Output:

```
onPySignal {'name': 'One', 'pk': 1}
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
onPySignal {'name': 'One', 'pk': 1.0}
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```